# Setters in VisualStateManager for Universal Applications

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp

It's quite normal in a `Setter` for a `VisualState` to set properties of a **child control**, but... is it possible to make the `Setter` change a property of the "Templated Control" in the context of a ControlTemplate?

Example: *this doesn't work:*

```
<VisualState x:Name="VerticalDisplay">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

Running it throws an exception and says this message:

> "WinRT information: The property 'Target' is missing from a Setter."

What target? I don't have a name to refer to "myself"! I want to change my own ItemsPanel.

I hope you understand what I want to do.

The whole Style is as follows (WizardControl derives from ListViewBase):

```
<Style TargetType="local:WizardControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WizardControl">
                <Border
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SizeModes">
                            <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                <VisualState x:Name="VerticalDisplay">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalDisplay">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup.States>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border x:Name="Root">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a workaround creaking a WizardControlHost that *hosts* the WizardControl inside, binds all the required properties (like ItemsSource) and plays with the ItemsPanel using Visual States.

You can see it here:
https://github.com/SuperJMN/WizardControl-UWP/blob/master/Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml#L164

I have determined that it's not possible to use VisualState Setters to modify properties of a Templated Control itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UserControl .. Create custom user control and make it your template .. then you can play with visual states as you want :) .

Comment: It's a Templated Control already (lookless) and it should be that by design.